# JS Symbol as object key

Tags: javascript, symbols

I'm running a node software where in a certain context of the software there is an object which one of it's keys is a Symbol, and it's value is an object. For example:

```
object = {Symbol(symbol_name): another_object}
```

I'm trying to get to the 'another_object' keys and values and can't find the way to do so. Suggestions anyone?

Comment: Use a computed property key

Comment: Hi Bergi, what does it means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best approach would be to save the Symbol in a variable first, then just use bracket notation to look it up:

```js
const sym = Symbol('symbol_name');
const object = {[sym]: { foo: 'bar' }}

console.log(object[sym]);
```

If you don't have a reference to the symbol, and the object contains only one symbol, you can get it with `getOwnPropertySymbols`:

```js
const object = {
  [Symbol('symbol_name')]: {
    foo: 'bar'
  }
};

const sym = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(object)[0];
console.log(object[sym]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much CertainPerformance, it worked!